# Pandas replicate n rows

Tags: pandas

I have a `dataframe` of this format:

```
UserID      num_attempts
abc123        4
def234        3
```

I am looking to transform it in such a way that the output is as follows

```
result_col
abc123
abc123
abc123
abc123
def234
def234
def234
```

Essentially create a new DF where there is one column, that is `UserID` repeated for each user for the `num_attempts`
apologies, I dont have a better way of wording this...but is there a pythonic way to achieve this? I would like to avoid a for loop...
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another possible solution:

```
pd.Series(
    [[x[0]] * x[1] for x in zip(df['UserID'], df['num_attempts'])], 
    name='result_col').explode()
```

---

Or, more compactly:

```
pd.Series([[x[0]] * x[1] for x in zip(*df.values.T)], 
    name='result_col').explode()
```

---

Output:

```
0    abc123
0    abc123
0    abc123
0    abc123
1    def234
1    def234
1    def234
Name: result_col, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Index.repeat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html) before reindexing the dataframe:

```
>>> df['UserID'].reindex(df.index.repeat(df['num_attempts']))
0    abc123
0    abc123
0    abc123
0    abc123
1    def234
1    def234
1    def234
Name: UserID, dtype: object
```

So to get expected result, do:

```
out = (df['UserID'].reindex(df.index.repeat(df['num_attempts']))
                   .to_frame('result_col').reset_index(drop=True))
print(out)

# Output
  result_col
0     abc123
1     abc123
2     abc123
3     abc123
4     def234
5     def234
6     def234
```

**Another way** with numpy and DataFrame constructor:

```
import numpy as np

pd.DataFrame(np.repeat(df['UserID'], df['num_attempts']).tolist(), 
             columns=['result_col'])
print(df)

# Output
  result_col
0     abc123
1     abc123
2     abc123
3     abc123
4     def234
5     def234
6     def234
```

Answer (score 2):

With [`split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html), [`mul`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mul.html) & [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) :

```
ser = df["UserID"].str.split(r"\x00").mul(df["num_attempts"]).explode()
```

Thanks to *@Corralien*, we use `r"\x00"` (*which represents the null character in Unicode*) as a regex pattern to potentially prevent the split to occur on a whitespace.

Ouptut :

```
0    abc123
0    abc123
0    abc123
0    abc123
1    def234
1    def234
1    def234
dtype: object
```

If you need a *DataFrame*, use :

```
(df["UserID"].str.split(r"\x00").mul(df["num_attempts"])
       .explode().reset_index(drop=True).to_frame("result_col"))
```

Comment: Take care about split if you have a whitespace in the userid like 'abc 123',

Comment: Is there a tricky regex that can handle this kind of scenario ?

Comment: Probably `r'\x00'` (or you can use an emoji. lol)